# HttpWebRequest - Is my code right?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I´m a little confused about my code because from time to time I get an Http 500 error message.
I know what an http 500 error (a Server error) is, but I want to be sure that my code is not the problem.

Do you think there could be something wrong with my code?

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testurls[samplenumber, j]);
System.Net.NetworkCredential netCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(test_user, test_pass, test_domain);
request.Timeout = 60000; 
request.Headers.Add("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 50 ;
request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 64 ;
request.Method = "GET";
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
stream.Close();
stream.Dispose();
response.Close();
```

Comment: does it work directly browsing URL from browser?

Comment: no it´s an standalone program

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your URLs come from a matrix. I don't know how many but likely some of them take you to pages that are returning HTTP 500 status code. Try logging those pages...

### UPDATE

embed your code in a try catch block like this.

```
try
{
}
catch (WebException)
{
// set a breakpoint here
}
```

And when the program stops in the breakpoint, then write this in your immediate window.

```
new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
```

You'll then get the details of the HTTP 500 which I hope to give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I get the URLs from a matrix, but at the moment I´m using only one URL. And I´m getting http 500 errors from time to time. But only when I´m using the code, not when I´m using a browser. I searched a lot in the Webserver config. And now I want to double check my code. To be sure that not my code is the problem.

Comment: OK, netCred variable doesn't seem to used (at least here) so you may remove it from your question. Why do you set the header HTTP_USER_AGENT as mozilla? The important part is in the update.

Comment: Hey Fabio, thanks for your answer! But I allready use a try/catch block and the response stream. You can not see it, because I copied only the conection part.I posted my code because I want to double check it and be sure that my code is not the reason for the http 500 errors.